# Get Two Sizes of Header Image

Tags: header-image, retina

My theme uses `header_image();` function to echo out a header image `<img src="...">` it is set to *200x50px* with `add_theme_support(...);` - all good here. My problem comes when I want to get the url of retina sized version of the image. Tried `get_header_image();` but it doesn't accept any parameters so can't pass custom size *(400x100px)*. How can I **(using WP's `header_image();`)** get the url of the retina-size version (400x100px) of the standard (200x50px) header image?

If it's not possible maybe we could try setting the default image demensions to 400x100px and resizing it down to 200x50px, and getting the url of a resized image?

Basically, I want to get two urls with the use of wp's core function - `header_image();`, one with 200x50px dimensions and one with 400x100px dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the Retina plugin. It automatically edits the line for you. Generating a retina image.

Comment: This is a very minimal answer-- not so much as a link to the plugin, and even with a link it would be less than adequate. Please browse the [Help]